# Test class of Rest API Services Failed

Tags: apex

[image]

```
public class SendAccountUsingRESTAPI {
      private final String clientId = 'REMOVED';
       private final String clientSecret = 'REMOVED';
       private final String username = 'REMOVED';
       private final String password = 'REMOVED';

        public static list<Account> Listacc{get;set;}
        public class deserializeResponse
       {
          public String id;
          public String access_token;
       }
      public String ReturnAccessToken (SendAccountUsingRESTAPI acount)
       {
          String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
          Http h = new Http();
          HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
          req.setBody(reqbody);
          req.setMethod('POST');

          req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
          HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
         deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
         system.debug('@@@@access_token@@'+resp1 );
          return resp1.access_token;
       }

       public static void callgetAccount ()
       {
               SendAccountUsingRESTAPI acount1 = new SendAccountUsingRESTAPI();
               String accessToken;
               accessToken = acount1.ReturnAccessToken (acount1);
               Listacc=new List<Account>();
               if(accessToken != null){
               //String endPoint = 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/getAccounts/';
               String endPoint = 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/getAccounts/';    
               //String jsonstr = '{"accId" : "' + accId+ '"}';
               Http h2 = new Http();
               HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
               req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
               req1.setHeader('accent-Type','application/json');
               req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
               //req1.setBody(jsonstr);
               req1.setMethod('GET');
               req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
               HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
               String trimmedResponse = res1.getBody().unescapeCsv().remove('\\');
               system.debug('@@@RESPONSE@@'+trimmedResponse);
               JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res1.getBody());
               set<Account> accList=new set<Account>();

                while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                    //Id

                    if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) ){
                        Account acc;
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'Id')) {

                        parser.nextToken();

                        string sId= parser.getText();
                        acc=new Account();
                        acc.Id=sId;
                        system.debug('Id@@@' + sId);

                        parser.nextToken();
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                            (parser.getText() == 'Name')) {

                            parser.nextToken();

                            string sName= parser.getText();
                            acc.Name=sName;

                        }


                        parser.nextToken();
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                            (parser.getText() == 'Industry')) {

                            parser.nextToken();

                            string indus= parser.getText();
                            acc.Industry=indus;

                        }
                            parser.nextToken();
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                            (parser.getText() == 'Rating')) {

                            parser.nextToken();

                            string rat= parser.getText();
                            acc.Rating=rat;

                        }


                    }
                    accList.add(acc); 
                    }     
                    accList.remove(null);

                }
                Listacc.AddAll(accList);
                system.debug('accList@@@@'+Json.serialize(Listacc));
       }

       }

    }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class zTest_SendAccountUsingRESTAPI {

    static testmethod void ApiTest1(){
        Account ac = new Account(name='Rohit');
        insert ac;
        test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WebServiceMocks.SendAccountMockHTTPResponseLogin());                
        SendAccountUsingRESTAPI accn = new SendAccountUsingRESTAPI();
        //accn.ReturnAccessToken(accn);
        SendAccountUsingRESTAPI.callgetAccount();
        test.stopTest();
    }
    static testmethod void ApiTest2(){
        Account ac = new Account(name='Rohit');
        insert ac;
        test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WebServiceMocks.SendAccountMockHTTPResponseLogin());                
        SendAccountUsingRESTAPI accn1 = new SendAccountUsingRESTAPI();
        String accessToken = accn1.ReturnAccessToken(accn1);
        SendAccountUsingRESTAPI.callgetAccount();
        test.stopTest();
    }
}

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   public class WebServiceMocks {

    public class SendAccountMockHTTPResponseLogin implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0016F00002cB1LVQA0"},"Id":"0016F00002cB1LVQA0","Name":"GenePoint","Industry":"Biotechnology","Rating":"Cold"}');            
            res.setStatusCode(200); 
            return res; 
        }
    }
}
```

While running
 test classes I got error system jsonexception malformed json expected
'{' at the beginning of object in test class.

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code, and always include the *verbatim, complete error message*.

Comment: Please also **never post actual credentials in your code**. You should change your password and replace your Connected App, because you posted those secret values in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your mock returns an array (as indicated by the `[` at the start):

```
res.setBody('[{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0016F00002cB1LVQA0"},"Id":"0016F00002cB1LVQA0","Name":"GenePoint","Industry":"Biotechnology","Rating":"Cold"}]');
```

but your code expects an object at the root of the JSON:

```
deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
```

Make the two pieces of code consistent.

See  https://www.json.org for more about the JSON format.

Comment: I have made the changes in the test class but still my test class is not covering the if condition of access token. I have attached the screenshot of my class above.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apex makes two separate callouts: one to acquire an access token, and one to hit your custom REST service. Your mock is only providing a mock response to the second call, and its response is not meaningful or correct for the first call.

Your mock class will need to inspect the `HTTPRequest` object it receives and return an appropriate response body based on the actual call being made. Optionally, you can streamline this by using the built-in [`MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm) class, which lets you store response JSON in a Static Resource you specify for each mocked endpoint.

It's not clear why you feel the need to use manual JSON parsing. Your code would be much cleaner if you instead used system-supplied deserialization.

I would also redesign the API of this class. Response values are being stored in an instance variable of an instance that is created within a `static` method and then never returned to the caller. This certainly won't work, but it's not clear what the intent is. I would make this a stateless service class with only `static` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David.How would I make the mock for the first call. How can I make the response useful for the first call.

Comment: Looks to me like you just need to create a mock response that includes a non-null access token.

Comment: Yes David I am having problem in creating a mock response that includes a non-null access token.Please help me for that.

Comment: You have already written a mock that provides a response for your other callout. You need to use the same techniques to provide a mock for this one. The access token does not have to be real.

Comment: Thank you ver much David for your suggestion.Finally I made the test coverage 100%.